# How to change the url with htaccess like wordpress

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a custom made php site where content loads depending on the query string. Now I want to change the total url to be like wordpress site where they don't show any query.

Example:

**Current page with query:** http://example.com/content.php?category=game&c=car-racing

**What I want:** http://example.com/game/car-racing

Is that possible?

If possible, then how do I write link **href** within the html code of php page? Will it be like

```
<a href="http://example.com/content.php?category=game&c=car-racing">Text</a>
```

or

```
<a href="http://example.com/game/car-racing">Text</a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Comment: funny that developer with 3 years experience don't know how to rewrite urls. there are tons of examples how to do url rewriting. why those PHP devs are so lazy? (:

Answer (score 0):

modify your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)& content.php?category=$1&c=$2 [QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But still, u would have to handle the links and separate them for each parameter. So rather than doing all that you can use Helium.
Try https://github.com/iamyogik/Helium